# Is it OK to use built-in function names for custom class methods in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A colleague of mine has defined a class with a method `print`. It is called as `instance.print()` to dump some text to stdout (it pretty much just wraps `print()`).

I feel like this is bad practice and want to suggest we refactor this but I can't think of any good reasons to justify this either.

Comment: I don't think this is a very bad practice. Both print functions belongs to different classes so both of them will do their respective work without shadowing. Still for readability they should not use builtin names.

Comment: If you cant think of a good reason does that not answer your question?

Comment: @NickA of course not, I don't consider myself an ultimate authority on Python :) the collective knowledge of SO on the other hand...

Comment: @deed a fair observation :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is bad practice. All of these decisions are very subjective and can be interpreted differently therefore I suggest reading the [official PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You can even include it with your editor to suggest changes!

Another massive reason why this is really bad practice is; while it works in Python3 as expected, in Python2 `print` was a name which precludes you from using it as an identifier, including a method name.

Comment: Which section of PEP8 are you referring to?\

Comment: In 2018 it already was not very important to take into consideration compatibility with Python 2.